# homology classes and maps to projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am looking for a reference or proof of the following fact:

Let $M$ be a 2n-dimensional closed manifold and $1<k<n$ an integer. For each (non-zero) class $\eta \in H^{2}(M,\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\eta^k =0$, there is a continuous map $\phi: M  \rightarrow \mathbb{CP}^{k-1}$ such that $\phi^{*}(H) = x \eta$ (over $\mathbb{R}$; for some $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$), $H$ is the hyperplane class.

Comment: Do you know some obstruction theory?

Comment: The relevant reference is M. Vigue's PhD thesis, where she defines obstructions to lifting functions on cohomology rings, [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1999744).

Comment: @Pedro Tamaroff, thanks! sorry for the slow reply. I browsed this thesis and couldn't find the above result. Please could you could provide a theorem number or page number?

Comment: https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1981-265-02/S0002-9947-1981-0610959-8/ is the relevant paper (free access, in French). The theorem is stated in the first page, and if I understand correctly it applies to your case because projective space has no odd cohomology and your manifold has finite cohomology: to realise a map $M\to N$ rationally you need at least $H^1(N,\mathbb Q)=0$ and $H^p(M,\mathbb Q)=0$ or large $p$. If this holds, then $f$ can be realized iff the obstructions defined by Vigue vanish.

Comment: ( I just realize that the link I gave above is *the same* paper. The result is stated in the first page. Did you miss that?)

Comment: Thanks, I saw it but I still don't quite understand how to apply it. I am happy to assume that my manifold satisfies $b_1=0$ but even then this result (assuming you are speaking about Corollary 3.1.5) only implies that maps from $\mathbb{CP}^1$ and $\mathbb{CP}^2$ are realisable since it assumed $b_{p}(M)=0$ for $p>4$ (in Vigue's notation). Anyway I did not know this so that is already good!. If the full statement follows from Vigues paper, then please provide the relevant theorem number.